# jQuery add Share Icon script

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharethis

I'm trying to add via jQuery the share icon [1].  Unfortunately I can't seem to do this as jQuery appears to escape the script code and I can't seem to get it to work with .text() or .html().

Has anyone gotten this, or something similar, working?

The code I'm trying is:

```
var enc = $('<div/>')
            .text('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/sharethis.js#publisher=faa9f152-cae0-4ff3-bab7-32ae934bc698&amp;type=website&amp;style=ro
            ;

$('<div/>')
    .appendTo(nav)
    .addClass('navItem')
    .append(eval(enc))
    ;
```

[1] http://sharethis.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.getScript(url, callback)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for loading scripts at runtime.

The callback is triggered when the script is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `html()` at the end to first **convert html tags to their entities** eg:

```
var enc = $('<div/>')
        .text('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/sharethis.js#publisher=faa9f152-cae0-4ff3-bab7-32ae934bc698&amp;type=website&amp')
.html();
```

More Info Here: http://debuggable.com/posts/encode-html-entities-with-jquery:480f4dd6-13cc-4ce9-8071-4710cbdd56cb